# Question on weak topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

i need help to solve this exercise please

"Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $K \subset E$ be a subset of $E$ that is compact in the strong topology. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ weakly $\sigma (E,E^*)$.
Prove that $x_n \rightarrow x$ strongly"

Please, thank you

Comment: As a Banach space, $E$ is a metric space. That means for subsets of $E$ compact and sequentially compact coincide. So you have a sequence in a sequentially compact set. And that sequence is also weakly convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume not then there is $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $\|x-x_{n_k}\|>\epsilon$ for all $k$. Call this fact (1).

Now $x_{n_k}\in K$ and so a subsequence of it must converge to a point $y\in K$ strongly. That must mean this subsequence also converges weakly and weak limits are unique. Thus $y=x$.

However this contradicts fact (1).

Comment: please juste why $x_{n_k}$ must converge strongly in $K$ ? thank you

Comment: $x_{n_k}$ might not converge but a subsequence of it does since $K$ is compact (in the strong topology).